# Python dataclasses inheritance with classes defined in different modules—bug workaround?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-module, python-dataclasses

I am using Python's very nice dataclasses module with inherited classes. The parent and child classes are in different modules like this:

`parent.py`

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Parent():
    p: int
```

`child.py`

```py
import dataclasses
import parent

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Child(parent.Parent):
    c: float
```

According to the [dataclasses documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#inheritance), a child class that inherits from a parent and both the child and parent use the `@dataclasses.dataclass`, the child `__init__` should first have the parent arguments. So, in my example, the `Child.__init__` should be:

```py
def __init__(self, p: int, c: float):
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work; I'm only getting the arguments to the child class as can be seen here:

```py
In [1]: import child

In [2]: import inspect

In [3]: inspect.signature(child.Child)
Out[3]: <Signature (c: float) -> None>
```

I believe this is a bug that has been reported [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85421), and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89687).

I thought this had been fixed in Python 3.10, but I downloaded 3.10.4 yesterday (via conda) and I'm still seeing the same problem.

---

So my question is: **Has this been fixed in a released version of Python?** If so, what version? If not, **what can I do?**

Comment: can not reproduce - is it a matter of child and parent in different modules? if not, it works fine on my machine

Comment: Sorry @python_user I forgot to add that when adding to StackOverflow. I've updated my question/example with the decoration.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Yes, it is precisely the fact that child and parent are in different modules; that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: @python_user So perhaps it got fixed in 3.10.5.

Comment: works on python 3.10.4 on my machine ... with 2 different modules

Comment: Ok, so this *has* been fixed---at least in version 3.10.4. I'm not sure what other versions.